# Reading files from an embedded ZIP archive

Tags: java, zip

I have a ZIP archive that's embedded inside a larger file. I know the archive's starting offset within the larger file and its length.

Are there any Java libraries that would enable me to directly read the files contained within the archive? I am thinking along the lines of [`ZipFile.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29). Unfortunately, [`ZipFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) doesn't work for this use case since its constructors require a standalone ZIP file.

For performance reasons, I cannot copy the ZIP achive into a separate file before opening it.

**edit:** Just to be clear, I do have random access to the file.

Comment: `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ZipInputStream(InputStream)` ?

Comment: Difficult. With a ZIP file, you need to read the directory first, which is at the end, so you need random access. You *could* read all the entries in one go from the beginning, and that would work with most zip files, but the format itself allows for funny things like duplicate entries and random junk data between entries.

Comment: @Thilo: Just to be clear, I do have random access to the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've come up with a quick hack (which needs to get sanitized here and there), but it reads the contents of files from a ZIP archive which is embedded inside a TAR. It uses Java6, FileInputStream, ZipEntry and ZipInputStream. '*Works on my local machine*':

```
final FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream("archive.tar");
// Zip starts at 0x1f6400, size is not needed
long toSkip = 0x1f6400;
// Safe skipping
while(toSkip > 0)
    toSkip -= ins.skip(toSkip);

final ZipInputStream zipin = new ZipInputStream(ins);
ZipEntry ze;
while((ze = zipin.getNextEntry()) != null)
{
    final byte[] content = new byte[(int)ze.getSize()];
    int offset = 0;
    while(offset < content.length)
    {
        final int read = zipin.read(content, offset, content.length - offset);
        if(read == -1)
            break;
        offset += read;
    }
    // DEBUG: print out ZIP entry name and filesize
    System.out.println(ze + ": " + offset);
}
zipin.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

1.create FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(..);

1. position it at the start of embedded zipfile:
   fis.skip(offset);
2. open ZipInputStream(fis)

Comment: that should work for most files, but the zip file format does allow for weird stuff like duplicate entries and random junk data between entries, so it would be better to have random-access and read the directory at the end of the archive first.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [TrueZIP](http://truezip.java.net/), it provides file system access to many kinds of archives. It worked well for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java SE 7, it provides a zip fie system which allows you to read/ write files in the zip directly: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Answer (score 0):

I think apache commons compress may help you.

There is a class `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry`, which inherit `java.util.zip.ZipEntry`.

It has a method `getDataOffset()`, that can get the offset of data stream within the archive file.

Answer (score -1):

[7-zip-JavaBinding](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a Java wrapper for the [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) C++ library.

The [code snippets](http://sevenzipjbind.sourceforge.net/basic_snippets.html) page in particular has some nice examples including printing a list of items in an archive, extracting a single file and opening multi-part archives.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php) helps you or not.

You can try [PartInputStream](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/lingala/zip4j/zip4j/1.2.3/zip4j-1.2.3-javadoc.jar!/net/lingala/zip4j/io/PartInputStream.html#PartInputStream%28java.io.RandomAccessFile,%20long,%20long,%20net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.UnzipEngine%29) to read zip file as per your use case.

I think it is better to create temp zip file and then accessing it.